# Reorganize a list

Tags: python, list

Hello i have this list and i want to transform this into the same list but just in minutes:

```
TR898 09:05
JX965 09:10
RE741 09:12
FR898 09:15
TY471 09:18
GE896 09:19
GE897 09:19
GE898 09:19
TZ423 09:20
TR453 09:20
TY473 09:21
TN423 09:21
XY423 09:23
GT423 09:25
TY513 09:21
```

.

```
Proposed_file_name = 'proposed.txt'
infile = open(Proposed_file_name, 'r')
i=0
line = infile.readlines()
while line != '':
    i=i+1
    part=line[1+i].split()
    IDS=part[0]
    dpart=(part[1].split(':'))
    hour=int(dpart[0])
    mints=int(dpart[1])
    total=(hour*60+mints)
    line = infile.readline()
else:
    infile.close()
print (total)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read and follow [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). In particular, just what output do you want? (Your description to too brief and unclear.) What is wrong with the code you show? If there was an error message, what is the full traceback?

Answer (score 0):

Edited the whole answer. Running the code below:

```
with open("proposed.txt", "r") as inFile:
    lines = [line for line in inFile]
    with open("out.txt", "w") as outFile:
        minuteTimes = []
        IDs = []
        newTimes = []
        for line in lines:
            content = line.split()
            IDs.append(content[0])
            time = content[1].split(":")
            finalTime = int(time[0]) * 60 + int(time[1])
            minuteTimes.append(finalTime)
        #i = 0
        newTime = minuteTimes[0] + 5
        newTimes.append((IDs[0], minuteTimes[0], 0))
        canGo = True
        for i in range(1,len(minuteTimes)):
            diff = minuteTimes[i] - minuteTimes[i-1]
            newDiff = newTime - minuteTimes[i]

            if diff == 5:
                newTimes.append((IDs[i], minuteTimes[i], diff))
                newTime = minuteTimes[i] + 5

            elif diff < 5:
                if newDiff > 15:
                    i += 1
                else:
                    minuteTimes[i] = newTime
                    newTimes.append((IDs[i], minuteTimes[i], diff))
                    newTime = minuteTimes[i] + 5
            else:
                newTimes.append((IDs[i], minuteTimes[i], diff))
                newTime = minuteTimes[i] + 5

        for n in newTimes:
            currentID = n[0]
            minutes = str(n[1] // 60).zfill(2)
            seconds = str(n[1] % 60).zfill(2)
            outFile.write(currentID + " " + minutes + ":" + seconds + '\n')
```

will give you the desired output:

```
TR898 09:05
JX965 09:10
RE741 09:15
FR898 09:20
TY471 09:25
GE896 09:30
TZ423 09:35
GT423 09:40
ZZSAQ 11:52
```

Comment: actually what im trying to do is a program that will take those times of flights and he will try to adjust them so the min difference between each one is 5 minutes and  for that if he need to delayed one more than 15 minutes he need to delete it

Comment: What have you tried so far? Could you provide the desired output of the above?

Comment: Edited my answer. It should give you the correct result. Feel free to upvote or accept as answer if it helped you.

Comment: Thank you very much for your precious help, but the problem is that the program make the time between exactly 5 min while i just want him to do that if the difference between two flights is less than 5min otherwise he don't need to change it.

Comment: in other words, if i add per exemple this flight: ZZSAQ 11:52 in my proposed.txt he need to be there in the output

Answer (score 0):

this is what i tried

```
with open("proposed.txt", "r") as inFile:
    lines = [line for line in inFile]
    with open("out.txt", "w") as outFile:
        for line in lines:
            content = line.split()
            time = content[1].split(":")
            finalTime = int(time[0]) * 60 + int(time[1])
            finalString = " ".join([content[0], str(finalTime), '\n'])
            outFile.write(finalString)
            while (finalTime-finalTime<5):
                Final=(finalTime-finalTime==5)
                outFile.write(Final)
            if  Final-finaltime>15:
                OutFile.write(Line)
```

And this is the desired output:

```
TR898 09:05
JX965 09:10
RE741 09:15
FR898 09:20
TY471 09:25
GE896 09:30
TZ423 09:35
GT423 09:40
```